# Sort the row of one matrix with respect to another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two different matrices `A` and `B`:

```
A =
  [7 8 9; 
   4 5 6]

B = 
  [22 32 12;
    9  8 10]

sortB = 
      [12 22 32;
        8  9 10]
```

`sortindex_B=[3 1 2;2 1 3];`, i.e., 12 is in the third position of matrix `B`, 22 in first, and 32 in second position; similarly for the second row.

Now I want to sort `A` depending on `Sortindex_B` (i.e., in matrix `A` I want 7 as the third element, 8 as the first, and 9 as the second element of the first row; and similarly for the second row: 4 at the second, 5 at the first, and 6 as the third element). Hence the result should look like:

```
A_final =
        [8 9 7;
         5 4 6]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the sorting index matrix from `sort` command, when sorting `B`, and thereafter operate on `A` as a cell, in so making `cellfun` available:

```
A = [7 8 9; 4 5 6];
B = [22 32 12; 9 8 10];
[sortB, I] = sort(B,2);

Icell = mat2cell(I,ones(1, size(I,1)),size(I,2));
Acell = mat2cell(A,ones(1, size(I,1)),size(I,2));
sortA = cell2mat(...
  cellfun(@(x,y) y(x), Icell, Acell, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Output (you state first row output as `8 9 7`, but did you really mean `9 7 8`?)

```
sortA =

     9     7     8
     5     4     6
```

---

For sorting as specifically specified in your question; re-map index matrix `I`:

```
A = [7 8 9; 4 5 6];
B = [22 32 12; 9 8 10];
[sortB, I] = sort(B,2);

%// re-map I
for i = 1:size(I,1)
  Itmp = I(i,:);
  for j = 1:size(I,2)
    I(i,Itmp(j)) = j;
  end
end

Icell = mat2cell(I,ones(1, size(I,1)),size(I,2));
ImapCell = mat2cell(Imap,ones(1, size(I,1)),size(I,2));
Acell = mat2cell(A,ones(1, size(I,1)),size(I,2));
sortA = cell2mat(...
  cellfun(@(x,y) y(x), Icell, Acell, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Output

```
sortA =

     8     9     7
     5     4     6
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea,,,But I do have 1000 rows ..and still it's not working for the second row,,,Is there any idea that we can do for all the row?

Comment: @userss I'm a bit uncertain of what kind of sorting you are looking for for matrix A: do you want matrix `A` to be sorted using the same swap operations as those used for matrix `B`? If so (and this would be the common case), the first solution in my answer above does this. If you however wants to use the specific sorting of `A` as you've described, I'll see what I can do, but please note that that sorting _is not performing the same swap operations as was done for `B`_, so please confirm that you actually want "your custom follow-up-sorting" done as described, before I proceed.

Comment: @userss Compare e.g. element `(row,column) = (1,1)` in your original matrices: value `7` in `A` and `22` in `B`. However in your matrix `A_final`, value `7` corresponds to `(1,3)`, whereas value `22` in `sortB` corresponds to `(1,2)`: i.e., values `7` and `22` are no longer "matched" after your sorting algorithm has finished: is this really as you have intended?

Comment: @userss Ok added a re-map for `I` index matrix to sort as you've requested (this re-map can probably be performed in a neater fashion without using nested for loops).

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `sort` as in dfri's answer and `sub2ind`:

```
A = [7 8 9; 
     4 5 6]; 
B = [22 32 12;
     9  8  10];

[sortB, sortindex_B] = sort(B,2);
[~, colIdx] = sort(sortindex_B,2);
rowIdx = ndgrid(1:size(B,1),1:size(B,2));
idx = sub2ind(size(B),rowIdx,colIdx);
sortA = A(idx)

ans =

   8   9   7
   5   4   6
```

Comment: Very concise and nice solution

Comment: Is there any way that I can do it for multiple rows?

Comment: Not sure I follow, this will work as is for any numbers of rows

Comment: This results: sortlA =[9 7 8; 5 4 6], but I want the output in the form of [ 8 9 7 ; 5 4 6]. because idx=[3 1 2;2 1 3];, i.e., 12 is in the third position of matrix B, 22 in first, and 32 in second position. Now I want to sort A depending on index_B (i.e., In matrix A: I want 7 as the third element, 8 as the first, and 9 as the second element of the first row; and similarly for the second row: 4 at the second, 5 at the first, and 6 as the third element). Hence the result should look like sortA=[ 8 9 7 ; 5 4 6].

Comment: @userss sorry I misread the question, should be fixed now. You just need the sort index of the sort index (i.e. just call `sort` again)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to do this row by row using the index values that the sort function returns.

Something like this should do the trick and is expandable to any number of rows that your matrix A and B may have. This does also validate that A and B are the same size before it continues.

```
B= [22 32 12; 9 8 10]
A = [7 8 9; 4 5 6];
assert(all(size(A) == size(B)));

sortB = zeros(size(B));
finalA= zeros(size(A));
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    [sorted,idx] = sort(B(i,:));
   sortB(i,:) = sorted;
   tempA = A(i,:);
   tempA = tempA(idx);
   finalA(i,:) = tempA;
end
```

Comment: This results:
finalA
     9     7     8
     5     4     6

Comment: This results:
finalA =[9 7 8; 5 4 6], but I want the output in the form of [ 8 9 7 ; 5 4 6]. 
   because   idx=[3 1 2;2 1 3];, i.e., 12 is in the third position of matrix B, 22 in first, and 32 in second position. Now I want to sort A depending on index_B (i.e., In matrix A:  I want 7 as the third element, 8 as the first, and 9 as the second element of the first row; and similarly for the second row: 4 at the second, 5 at the first, and 6 as the third element). Hence the result should look like finalA=[ 8 9 7 ; 5 4 6].

Answer (score 0):

There are many clever ways to do this, including this `for` loop. I hope the comments will explain the logic.

```
clear; %// input the sample data
A = [7 8 9; 4 5 6];
B = [22 32 12; 9  8 10];
sortB =  [12 22 32; 8  9 10];

%// loop through every element in B
[R C]=size(B);
for i=1:C
    for j=1:R
    %// Where does A(j,i) need to go in Afinal?
    %// It needs to go in the j-th row, and in
    %// whatever column of B(j,:) equals sortB(j,i).
    Afinal( j , find( B(j,:) ==sortB(j,i)) ) = A(j,i);
    end
end
```

And the result:

```
>> Afinal
Afinal =
     8     9     7
     5     4     6
```